# Proper PC Suite for android?

Tags: contacts, sms, remote-control

I was expecting Android Phones to have some powerful PC Suite, but apparently not.
I'm looking for application that can:

- manage my phone files (audio/photo),
- calendar (ms outlook independent)
- add/remove applications,
- access/edit/merge/remove contacts (ms outlook independent)
- send SMS messages

This features are pretty common for most mobiles, and I'm wondering is there anything like that available for Android phones?

Comment: MoboPlay has a really user-friendly UI and lots of features. I recommend it!
http://www.moboplay.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're looking for an app that behaves like the Suites of yesteryear ;-), try [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/en/highlight.php). Here's a short list of features:

Features:

- Addressbook - with direct sync to Outlook, GMail, Windows contacts, Thunderbird, SeaMonkey, Lotus Notes and Tobit David
- Organizer with calendarview and direct sync to Outlook, Google, Sunbird, Thunderbird, SeaMonkey, Windows calendar(Vista), Rainlendar, Lotus Notes, Tobit David and net shared calendars (WebDAV, FTP, local)
- SMS - archive, export, import, excessive messages,...
- Filebrowser with cachesystem to minimize datatransfer, automatic photosync...
- Set phoneclock based on atomtime
- and much more. such as : calllists, edit profiles, control phone, memorystatus, phonemonitor,...

Comment: That is awesome piece of software

Answer (score 15):

That's the beauty of Android. You don't *need* a separate piece of software for your PC. It's designed from the ground up to do everything within the Cloud.

> - manage my phone files (audio/photo),

Connect via USB, turn on USB drive mode, and use Windows Explorer to manage your files.

> - calendar (ms outlook independent)

Sync over-the-air (OTA) to Google Calendar.

> - add/remove applications,

You do that right on the device or in the [Google Play Store](http://play.google.com/store/apps).

> - access/edit/merge/remove contacts (ms outlook independent)

Sync OTA with Google Contacts.

> - send SMS messages

There are [some apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/send-sms-from-pc-through-android-phone-or-to-android-phone) that allow you to do that.

Comment: Winamp will let you sync music to your phone (even wirelessly).

Comment: Having everything on mobile is great, but nothing would replace big screen and proper keyboard. Storing all your private data online is doubtfully good idea.

Comment: Then an Android probably isn't for you. It's a fundamental part of the design.

Comment: Just to add, you can now also install applications from the web from https://market.android.com/.

Comment: @Lie: Indeed, although you can't uninstall from there.

Comment: @Nazariy: Syncing in Android works both way, this means you can add/edit/delete your Calendar/Contact on the web version of Google Calendar or Gmail Contact on a browser in a big screen and big keyboard and it will sync seamlessly with Android.

Comment: Using the new Android Market Website http://market.android.com it is possible to install new apps onto the phone (and see all installed apps)

Answer (score 4):

## Desktop Apps

1. [**PandaApp PC Suite**](http://91.pandaapp.com/pcsuite/)

   This is a full fledge PC Suite for android (much like nokia pc suite). And has interface better the myphoneexplorer

   It has all features you need.
   File manager,
   Sms Manager
   Screen Capture
   Application Installer
   etc..

   [image]
2. **Hi Suit**
   This is for Huawei IDEOS phones, I don't know if it can work with other phones as well.
   It can be downloaded from Huawei IDEOS page, [link](http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/productFeatures.do?pinfoId=2831&directoryId=3902&treeId=3606)
   [Direct Link](http://www.huaweidevice.com/tcpsdownload/downLoadCenter?category=&flay=software&fileName=110309033615.zip&attachmentName=U8800%20PC%20%28U8800%20Hi%20%20suit%29.zip)
   [image]
3. [**HiAPK PC Suit**](http://download.pchome.net/home/mobile/general/detail-178156.html)

   [image: HiAPK PC Suite]

---

## Webapps

**[AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en)**
[image]

---

[This link](http://www.tipsotricks.com/2012/02/best-android-pc-suite-software.html) lists 10 good PC Suites for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this [Android PC suite](http://www.android-file-transfer.com/):
[image]

Comment: Please confirm whether you're associated with this product or its vendor. Promoting your own (relevant) products on this site is fine **only** if you are honest about it, and I'll note that the vendors of this product have spammed this site before.