# How to install LG Optimus One PC Suite on Mac?

Tags: usb, lg-optimus-one, macos

For the LG Optimus One the PC suite and USB driver are all Windows-based. My home computer is an IMac.

Are there versions of these downloaads that will work with my Mac?

Comment: related question: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6034/482

Comment: Are you trying to do something specific? Sync contacts, transfer media, update firmware?

Comment: Thank you for response.At this stage I am only trying to follow procedure of connecting my P 500 to the computer as per the manual. Ultimately this is to access updates. I did find some similar posts from mac users. Oh, my contacts all sync-ed automatically from my gmail and I did work out via unbugging usb and mounting sd card how to transfer music. My concern is that this is piecemeal and my real issue is on updates.