# Is there an app that will let me text from my pc with the same phone number?

Tags: sms, motorola-droid-x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send SMS from PC through Android Phone or to Android Phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/send-sms-from-pc-through-android-phone-or-to-android-phone)

I have a Droid x, and I wanted to know if there is an app that will allow me send and receive text messages from my computer through my phone (meaning receive the messages that are sent to my phone) without using something that will give me a dedicated phone number, I want to use the phone number on my cell phone. does anybody know if this exists. if it does, and there is more than one, which one is the best?

Answer (score 3):

[Texter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dkfhfaphfkopdgpbfkebjfcblcafcmpi) is a Google Chrome extension/Android app that will let you compose, send, and receive text messages in Google Chrome by connecting to your phone.  So it just forwards received messages from your phone to Chrome, and sent messages from Chrome to your phone.