# Typing/sending text messages using Kies

Tags: sms

Does the Kies software allow one to type and send text messages from the PC?

Comment: See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/how-do-i-send-sms-from-pc-through-android-phone-or-to-android-phone

Comment: Please mark this question as answered

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

But, on the other hand, you can use the Kies Air application, which you can obtain through Samsung Apps. It allows you to access your mobile on the desktop browser if both PC and phone share the same Wifi network.

Then you would be able to send/recv messages on the desktop, amid many other things like accessing photos, videos, contacts, call logs, music, file system... and so on.  It is like a small web interface to your mobile.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not support sending text messages on PC

Answer (score 0):

Kies Air does support sending of SMS thru PC. You need to connect the PC and your handset with the same network.

Comment: Could you provide a link to your source? Or provide a better description? Just the other two answers say you can't.

Answer (score 0):

**Samsung Kies - USB connection to PC:** doesn't support SMS sending
**Kies Air - Wi-Fi connection with device:** supports SMS sending

Answer (score -1):

Try using MyPhoneExplorer.  This allows SMS sending from computer via android machines.  I've been using it for years.