# There is an app to send/read SMS from the desktop using the Internet?

Tags: applications, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I send SMS from PC through Android Phone or to Android Phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/how-do-i-send-sms-from-pc-through-android-phone-or-to-android-phone)

There are many apps to send/read SMS from the desktop using a Wi-Fi connection, but my cyanogenmod rom doesn't play nice with my Thomson router so I can't use them.

There is an app that uses the 3G internet connection for that?

Better if it's a webapp.

Comment: Have you tried using CWM's [DeskSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.desktopsms) ?

Comment: I don't get it: If your ROM doesn't work with your WiFi connection at home, then it should fall back to 3G anyway. Or do you mean that the app should also work over a internet connection instead of just the local LAN? In that case, try one of the many answers of the duplicate question.

Comment: For example airdroid and many similar apps use the wifi connection to connect with a local server on pc. The question is about apps that will use a remote server on the internet so I can connect using 3g

Comment: The other question is different and not duplicate because many solutions are assuming that the phone can access the local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I need!

There is [Mightytext](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.texty.sms), [mobitexter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mobitexter) and [mysms](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mysms.android.sms).

For now I use Mightytext, because it looks to be the best. (Also it weighs at less than 500k, that's great for my phone)

Answer (score 1):

I have used [DeskSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.desktopsms) over a Wi-Fi tether, and it works fine.

It is supposed to work over 3G, but I have not tested this.

Comment: I don't really like it because it causes too much clutter in my gmail