# Is there a way to receive my SMS messages on my desktop?

Tags: sms

I just purchased an S4 Mini, my first android phone. I was wondering - is there a way to send/receive messages on my Windows 8 desktop when my phone is connected to my machine?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [How do I send SMS from PC through Android Phone or to Android Phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1784)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wish to run a search on Google Play. One good choice will be [Airdroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/airdroid/com.sand.airdroid), which gives you a full remote maintenance suite. And of course you can send/receive SMS using any browser you like.

Comment: What kind of search would I be running? I don't quite know what these kinds of applications are called and although I've had a cursory look, I had no luck

Comment: I'd try startimg with "remote management". But that might turn up lots of things you're not after. You might want to check [this list of alternatives](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/427833/) (don't mind the German, just see the app-links below "Vollverwaltung" for alternatives to Airdroid).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SMS Text Messaging ↔PC Texting](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.texty.sms).

```
★ Send & Receive SMS on your computer ot tablet.

★ Instant Notifications on computer/tablet when SMS hits phone.
```

Answer (score 0):

Or how about [Kies Air](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.swift.app.kiesair)?
You can connect to your pc using Wi-Fi and there are more functionalities than just texting.
There is no need for a cable. This could be a plus or a min.

> Without having to connect any cables, within a browser you can use diverse function such as multimedia transfer, music listening, PIMS management, text message, file search, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For a Windows 8 PC, you should try mysms. It has an [native Windows 8 client](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/mysms-text-from-computer/7acc83af-5362-4705-8490-b1869a30367a)

You can send/reveive texts on your Windows 8 PC via your mobile operator. Your PC and your phone will stay in sync.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using [Mighty Text](http://mightytext.net/) for about 6 months now. Works really well and has enough other features too.